# Why did this automatic expansion array fail?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> 

int main() {
  char c;
  int n = 10;
  int *p = (int*) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
  int i = 0, j = 0;

  do {
    scanf("%d", (p + i++));
    c = getchar();
    if (i == n / 2) {
      (int*) realloc(p, n * 2 * sizeof(int));
      n = n * 2;
    }
  } while (c != '\n');

  for (; j < i; j++) {
    printf("%d ", *(p + j));
  }
  free(p);
}
```

I need an automatic expansion array, when the user input half of the array, it will expand two times bigger than before, and maybe it worked.   But when I input more number into the array, some of the former number are lost.  I don't know why this can happened.  Why realloc function fail to copy the former numbers?

like this

```
1 2 3 2 2 1 2 3 2 1 2 4 5 3 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 2 3 2 1

1990352 0 1973264 0 2 1 2 3 2 1 2 4 5 3 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 2 3 2 1
```

Comment: `realloc` *returns* the new pointer, it doesn't modify it in place.  No C function can modify its argument (unless you pass a pointer to it).

Comment: The code is hard to read because it is not indented in an orthodox style.  You should check the return value from `scanf()` to ensure you're not processing erroneous data.  Use subscripts — they're easier to read: `&p[i++]` is simpler than `(p+i++)`, for example.

Answer (score 4):

The return value of `realloc()`, the newly allocated pointer, is unused in OP's code.

Save the returned value, test for success, then assign.

```
// (int*)realloc(p,n*2*sizeof (int));

// Instead
void *new_p = realloc(p, sizeof *p * n * 2);
if (new_p == NULL) {
  Handle_allocation_failure();  // User code here
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
p = new_p;
n = n*2;
```

---

Avoid sizing to the type as it is error prone.  Sizing to the type of the de-referenced pointer is easy to code right, review and maintain.  Casts not needed.

```
// Idiom
ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr * n);
```